# Parsing unknown amount of lines and assigning them to vars

Tags: c++

So, I wanted to create an easy program, but since my c++ lessons have passed 2 years and I dont clearly remember some things. Program is for quick switching steam accounts. I do it only for me and my friends (we have a lot of accs) and just for training. It must parse an unknown amount of steam accounts from file(syntax - login=xxxx,pass=yyyy) and assign them to vars. How can I create vars for each login and password?

I've tried like this

```
string line;
ifstream accfile("steamaccountswitcher");

if (!accfile)
{
    ofstream newaccfile("steamaccountswitcher");    //Create a new file, if doesnt exist
    newaccfile.close();
}

int lcounter = 1, pos = 0;
map<string, int> login, pass;

while (getline(accfile, line))  //Getting lines
{
    pos = line.find(",");   //Locating sparator

    for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++)   //Setting login var
    {
        login["lcounter"] += line[i];
    }

    for (int i = pos; i < sizeof(line); i++)    //Setting pass var
    {
        pass["lcounter"] += line[i];
    }

    lcounter++;
}
```

But it isnt working. Maybe there's a really stupid mistake, but I dont see it. Just for now I need login var to be "login=xxxxx" and pass var - "pass=yyyyy"

Example of steamaccountswitcher file:

```
login=1234,pass=4567
login=1111,pass=2222
login=2222,pass=2222
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: "It isn't working" isn't a useful description of a problem.

Comment: Why not use `std::vector`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `pos` is the position of `,`, so you have to begin with `pos + 1` to get `pass=yyyyy`, not `,pass=yyyyy`.
- `sizeof(line)` is not a good way to get the length of the string. You should use `line.size()` for that purpose.
- Using `std::string::substr()` is better in this case.
- `"lcounter"` do differ to `lcounter` and your program will concatenate data from all lines in one data.
- `int` cannot hold strings.
- You should use proper type for `pos`, which stores the return value of `std::string::find()`.

Try this:

```
int lcounter = 1;
string::size_type pos = 0;
map<int, string> login, pass;

while (getline(accfile, line))   //Getting lines
{
    pos = line.find(",");   //Locating sparator
    if (pos == string::npos) continue;   // For safety

    login[lcounter] = line.substr(0, pos);   //Setting login var

    pass[lcounter] = line.substr(pos + 1);   //Setting pass var

    lcounter++;
}
```